# Tabbar can't display the image

Tags: iphone, tabbar

In my a subclass of `uiviewcontroller`, implement the delegate method `UITabBarControllerDelegate`. My init method like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    NSMutableArray *viewControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [viewControllersArray addObject:Originalviewcontroller];
    [viewControllersArray addObject:differentviewcontroller];
    [viewControllersArray addObject:tradeviewcontroller];
    UITabBarController *uitabbarcontroller = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    uitabbarcontroller.delegate = self;
    uitabbarcontroller.viewControllers = viewControllersArray;
    [_shanghaitradeviewcontroller.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"OriginalMarket.png"] tag:1];
    [_shanghaidifferentviewcontroller.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DifferentMarket.png"] tag:2];
    [_shanghaitradeviewcontroller.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Trade.png"] tag:3];
    [self.view addSubview:uitabbarcontroller.view];
}
```

Everything seems normal, but the first image can't display, why?

**UPDATE**:
So sorry, I found the answer because I make a mistake:

`[_shanghaitradeviewcontroller.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"OriginalMarket.png"] tag:1];`

And should be:

`_shanghaiOriginalviewcontroller = [[ShanghaiOriginalMarketViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ShanghaiOriginalMarketViewController" bundle:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

First of all - in this code you leaking *viewControllersArray* and *uitabbarcontroller*

I think problem in the name of the image or image not added to the build target.
Find file than not displaying in **project navigator** and in **Target membership** set checkbox of your target checked